# Solve improper integral using Cauchy Residue Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, residue-calculus

I have
$$ I=\operatorname{PV} \int_{0}^{\infty} {\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x(1-x^2)}}\mathrm dx $$
I want to solve this using Cauchy Residue Theorem but I am unable to figure out $f(x)$. I have countour and poles $0,-1,1$ but I am not able to proceed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

$\frac{sin(πx)}{x(1-x^2)}= \frac{sin(πx)}{x} + \frac{xsin(πx)}{1-x^2}$

It's basically partial fraction of the denominator